# Switch Selection Multiple/Single UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm managing a `UITableView` where I'm trying to implement Multiple/Single selection

Initially `myTableView` has set `Selection: Single Selection` in `storyboard`.

When I select a `Row` in `myTableView` the info is displayed in another screen as desired.

As select options I have **Select...** and **Clear Selection**

**Select...** will enable the `Selection: Multiple Selection` to be able to select more than one row at the time and

**Clear Selection** will change again the `Selection` type to: `Single Selection`

I have tried with:

```
[self.myTableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[self.myTableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
```

To change Single to Multiple selection, but is not working

Is there a way to switch `Selection` property programmatically?

Comment: Just read up on [UiTableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview) , there are properties like allowsSelection and allowsMultipleSelection that will let you set those properties

Comment: You can just add a bool selection variable to your data source, then work with it, probably uitableview already have them already

Comment: Sorry guys, I have tried with `[self.myTableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];` but no luck, I edited the question adding that

Comment: How is -setAllowsMultipleSelection{DuringEditing} being called? I don't know this for certain, but it's possible that it needs to be called on the UI thread in order for the UITableView to be updated. Have you tried dispatching that call to the main thread?

Comment: Hmm I calling it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of another `tableView`, I have also called in `viewdidLoad` to change it's value, but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableView`'s `allowsMultipleSelection` property.  `YES` for multiple selection mode and `NO` for single selection mode.

See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview?language=objc

So something like the following may be all that you need:

```
- (IBAction)toggleMultipleSelection:(id)sender {
    myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = ! myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection;
}
```

(Note that this applies only when in non-editing mode.  There is another similar property for editing mode:  `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing`)

I don't know what happens if you set `.allowsMultipleSelection` to `NO` (ie, set to single selection mode) when there are already multiple cells selected.  You may need to manually clear the selections yourself when you change from multiple to single selection mode.

Comment: Thank you, but is not working :( I previously tried with `[self.myTableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES]; [self.myTableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];`, but is not working

Comment: I'm sorry as I was using JASidePanels the code has been reached but not really executed, using a `NSNotification` in my case, to execute that piece of code make it works, thank you Son of a Beach :)